# TableView is not updated with the new cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a simple app that display various cells , one for capture, in a table view.
For testing purpose I have add some example cells that are loaded from

```
var captures = [Capture]()
```

and it works.
When i try to add new captures into captures array they are not displayed.
This is my CapturesTableViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class CapturesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: Properties
var capture : Capture!
var captures = [Capture]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the sample data.
    loadSampleCaptures()

}

func loadSampleCaptures() {
    let photo1 = UIImage(named: "photo1")
    let capture1 = Capture(photo: photo1, name: "Barracuda", weight: 0.8, bait: "Duo tide flyer", notes: "prima cattura")

    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "photo2")
    let capture2 = Capture(photo: photo2, name: "Barracuda", weight: 1.2, bait: "Nemesi 18g", notes: "")

    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "photo3")
    let capture3 = Capture(photo: photo3, name: "Spigola", weight: 1.5, bait: "assassino", notes: "prima spigola")

    captures += [capture1!,capture2!,capture3!]
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return captures.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "CaptureTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CaptureTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let capture = captures[indexPath.row]

    cell.fishName.text = capture.fishName
    cell.fishPhoto.image = capture.photo
    cell.fishWeight.text = "\(capture.fishWeight) Kg"

    return cell
}



@IBAction func unwindToCaptureList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? NuovaCatturaViewController , capture = sourceViewController.capture{
        // Add a new capture
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: captures.count, inSection: 0)
        captures.append(capture)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Right)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

 }
```

[image]

I call unwindToCaptureList method from another scene and the if statement is executed and the capture is not nil.
Why is it not displayed?
Yet I am following the official tutorial apple (Food Tracker App) as a guideline.

UPDATE: 
I have tried  to add more entry and on the third entry it start to work fine.
[image]
How is it possible?

Comment: Don't use `reloadData()` right after `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. The insertion operation rearranges the table view automatically.

Comment: I have removed reloadData() and I still have the same behavior explained in Update

Comment: Then it's probably a timing problem while unwinding. Can you place the code to add the item somewhere else? Or use a callback closure.

Comment: Do you mean so?`addCapture()`

Comment: Try the following: Create a boolean variable `var shouldAppend = false`. Then in `unwindToCaptureList` set the variable to `true` and move the append/insert logic to `viewWillAppear`. In `viewWillAppear` check if `shouldAppend` is `true` . If yes, append/insert the item and reset `shouldAppend` to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you connected your method to your other view and do you know if it is executing? Add a print("Test") to check if the method is executed like below

```
@IBAction func unwindToCaptureList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? NuovaCatturaViewController , capture = sourceViewController.capture{
            // Add a new capture
            print("Is this executed?: \(capture)")
            print("Check dataSource before appending: \(self.captures)")
            self.captures.append(capture)
            print("Check dataSource after appending: \(self.captures)")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to change your code to what I have done in my answer. It should only be necessary to add object to tableView source and to update the tableview.